# Finding a point on the lagrangian constraint that maximizes a function

Tags: calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Use Lagrange multiplier to maximize $f\left( x,y \right) =x^3y^5$ subject to constraint $
g\left( x,y \right) =x+y=8$. We need to find all points $(x,y)$ that satisfy the condition:
$$
\begin{align}
\nabla f=\lambda \nabla g ,\\
\langle f_x\left( x,y \right) ,f_y\left( x,y \right) \rangle =\lambda \langle g_x\left( x,y \right) ,g_y\left( x,y \right) \text{)}\rangle ,\\
f_x\left( x,y \right) =3y^5x^2, f_y\left( x,y \right) =5x^3y^4 ,\\
f_x=\lambda g_x,f_y=\lambda g_y ,\\
f_x=\lambda ,f_y=\lambda ,\\
3y^5x^2=\lambda ,5x^3y^4=\lambda  ,\\
\end{align}
$$

Given the constrain is $g\left( x,y \right) =x+y=8$.

Suppose $\lambda =0$ , then either $x$ or $y$ are equal to 0, but that contradicts equation $x+y=8$, it means the point does not lie on the constraint.

**Question**: may I know please why the point does not lie on the constraint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

If $3x^2y^5=5x^3y^4$ then $3y=5x$ and so you have a system
$$5x-3y=0$$
$$x+y=8$$
to solve.

Comment: Thank you. That can be "solved" using elimination method

Comment: I am glad to be useful